# POM.xml runs fine but still the imports of the java files are not resolved

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have not used Maven much but I know it first checks into the local repository for the desired jar files and if not found there it downloads it from a mentioned repository. 
In my program, the jar files are present at the desired location inside the local repository.
pom.xml file also runs fine but still the program is not able to find the imports in any of the files.

Test class in the Program:

```
import javax.persistence.Cacheable;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;
public class TestAnnotation {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        EntityManagerFactory factory=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("annotation");
        EntityManager manager=factory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction=manager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();    
        manager.persist(new Message("My Entity Test One More Example New"));
        transaction.commit();
        System.out.println("First time calling Message Object");
        getMessage(manager,23);
        System.out.println("Second time calling Message Object");
        getMessage(manager,23);

        factory.close();
    }


    public static void getMessage(EntityManager manager,long id){
        EntityTransaction transaction1=manager.getTransaction();
        transaction1.begin();   
        Query q=manager.createQuery("from Message m where m.id="+id);
        Message m=(Message)q.getSingleResult();
        System.out.println(m.getMessage_text());
        transaction1.commit();
    }
}
```

Simple POJO in the program:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

@Entity
@Table(name="MESSAGES")
@Cache(region = "messages", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)

public class Message {

    Message(){

    }
    Message(String message){
        message_text=message;
    }
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="MESSAGE_ID")
    public Long id;
    @Column(name="MESSAGE_TEXT")
    public String message_text;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMessage_text() {
        return message_text;
    }
    public void setMessage_text(String message_text) {
        this.message_text = message_text;
    }
}
```

And finally the problematic pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>HibernateWithAnnotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>HibernateWithAnnotation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>HibernateWithAnnotation</name>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>codelds</id>
            <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1-Final</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

pom.xml doesnt contain any error as such. It runs fine for the goals - `clean package`.
But still the imports used in my java files are not resolved. 
There must be something silly happening by me somewhere. Please point it out to me.

Comment: Did you run the install goal also? Install goal actually does the job of configuring the required jar on the class path

Comment: @RachitAgrawal yup it also runs fine.

Comment: You are running via command line or eclipse pluggin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using eclipse..

Try executing `mvn eclipse:eclipse` . This sets up all the required classpath entries.

Comment: yup I am doing everything in eclipse. You mean I should run this command from the cmd

Comment: Yes you can. navigate to the directory of the project and run this command. Then refresh the project in eclipse. That should do it

Answer (score 1):

Go to the directory containing `pom.xml`.
open command prompt and run the following command :

```
mvn install
```

Then go back to eclipse refresh your project. All dependencies would be configured

Comment: mvn install only builds, packages and installs it your target and local repo. It wouldnt modify the classpath file as far as my knowledge goes.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different things - developing with IDE and building everything with maven.

Maven is standalone thing and it does not know anything of IDEs you use.

You have to either configure you favorite IDE-maven plugin, or just add the jars to the classpath by hand

Answer (score 0):

Maven dependencies are used only during run time. If you are using any kind of IDE to code, you have to add the required jars to class path so that when ever you type, the suggestions and reference comments will be shown for your keyword.